# Add custom local types to output declarations generated by TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider you have the following code in your library project:

```typescript
// src/index.ts

import { sum } from '@acme/sum';

export function printSum(a: number, b: number, sumFunc: typeof sum) {
  console.log(`The sum is: ${sumFunc(a, b)}`);
}
```

You are importing `sum` function from the untyped third-party package and using it as a type for function argument `sumFunc`.

Then you add local custom type declaration for this module:

```typescript
// types/acme-sum/index.d.ts

declare module '@acme/sum' {
  export function sum(a: number, b: number): number;
}
```

However, the compiled result will look like this:

```typescript
// dist/types/index.d.ts

import { sum } from '@acme/sum';
export declare function printSum(a: number, b: number, sumFunc: typeof sum): void;
```

As you can see, all custom typings are gone. If user of your library would import it, she won't be able to figure out what `sumFunc` type is.

Is there a way to make sure that local types are actually added to the output of `tsc`?